# Missing or insufficient permissions on setRoot - firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, ionic3, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I have a ionic angular application where i use email authentication. Basically once user logs in I navigate them to my tabs page and on logout I navigate them back to login page. Everything was working fine and recently I create rules for my collections as follows :

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /applications/{document=**} {
      allow read,write;
    }
    match /observations/{document=**} {
        allow read,write;
    }
    match /users/{document=**} {
        allow read,write
    }
  }
}
```

And after setting up these rules, I get this `FireStore - Missing or insufficient permissions` error when I hit the `signOut()` function and I couldn't find a way out of it.

This is my `login.ts` file

```
import { FetchData } from './../../services/fetchdata.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { LoaderService } from './../../services/loader.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html'
})

export class LoginPage {
    logSwitch: string;
    user: object = {};
    reguser: any = {};
    loaderlogin: any;
    alert: any;
    authstate: Observable<any>;
    topLoader: boolean = false;
    emailVerified: boolean = false;
    registeredname: string;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
        private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        private loaderService: LoaderService,
        private zone: NgZone,
        private fetchData: FetchData) {
        this.logSwitch = 'switchLog';
        this._navigateUser();
    }

    _navigateUser() {
        this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) { //&& user.emailVerified
                this.emailVerified = false;
                this.logSwitch = 'switchLog';
                this.topLoader = false;
                if (!user.emailVerified) {
                    user.sendEmailVerification();
                }
                if (user.displayName === null) {
                    user.updateProfile({
                        displayName: this.registeredname,
                        photoURL: null
                    }).then(() => {

                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                }
            }
            if (user && user.emailVerified) {
                this.zone.run(() => {
                    this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
                });
            }
        })
    }

    loginUser(user: any) {
        this.loaderlogin = this.loaderService.showLoader("Logging In!!");
        this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
            .then((data) => {
                this.loaderlogin = this.loaderService.dismissLoader();
                this.fetchData.setLocalData(data);
                if (!data.emailVerified) {
                    this.alert = this.loaderService.showAlert("Please verify your email to login!!");
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                this.loaderlogin = this.loaderService.dismissLoader();
                if (error.code === "auth/user-not-found") {
                    this.alert = this.loaderService.showAlert("User does not exist!!");
                } else if (error.code === "auth/wrong-password") {
                    this.alert = this.loaderService.showAlert("Wrong password!!");
                }
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    registerUser(regUser: any) {
        this.loaderService.showLoader("Registering User!!");
        this.registeredname = regUser.name;
        this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(regUser.email, regUser.password)
            .then((data) => {
                this.loaderlogin = this.loaderService.dismissLoader();
                this.fetchData.createUser({ uid: data.uid, username: regUser.name, email: regUser.email });
                this.alert = this.loaderService.showAlert("User successfully registered!");
                this.emailVerified = true;
                this.clearValues();
            }).catch((error) => {
                this.loaderlogin = this.loaderService.dismissLoader();
                if (error.code === "auth/email-already-in-use") {
                    this.alert = this.loaderService.showAlert("User already registered. Please Sign In!");
                }
            })
    }

    clearValues() {
        this.reguser.name = '';
        this.reguser.email = '';
        this.reguser.password = '';
        this.reguser.confpassword = '';
    }
}
```

and this is my `logout.ts` file

```
import { LoginPage } from './../login/login';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { LoaderService } from '../../services/loader.service';
import { App } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-contact',
  templateUrl: 'contact.html'
})
export class ContactPage {
  alert: any;
  username: string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private loaderService: LoaderService,
    public appCtrl: App,
    private zone: NgZone) {
    this.username = localStorage.username;

  }

  signOut() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then((res) => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(LoginPage);
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.alert = this.loaderService.showAlert("Unable to logout. Try Again!");
    })
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It would help a lot to know when the `FireStore - Missing or insufficient permissions` error shows up.

Comment: Hi, it happens when I hit my `signOut() ` function in my `logout.ts`. I use `setRoot()` to navigate back to the LoginPage and that's exactly when the error appears.I'm not making any calls to my firestore in LoginPage other than when registering and logging in both of which triggers only on button click. I suspect if it is because of the `onAuthStateChanged() ` observer but don't know how to get around this issue.

Comment: Hey it happens because you're logging out and it is still listening to the database before it takes the user to the login screen.

You can either ignore it (_if it doesn't break the app_) or you can disconnect from the collection you're listening before logging out

Comment: Is it in the logout.ts file? But I'm not listening to db in my logout.ts file

Comment: logout page isn't listening, but you have active connections throughout the app